# Tails 2.0 Issue script is running on shutdown

Tags: tails

I recently downloaded tails 2.0. I verified the signature through Ubuntu. Through command line. It gave a positive verification. On shut down of the tails 2.0. The normal screen comes up where it say the display will power down and to remove the DVD or USB drive. But instead of the DVD drive getting ejected some script starts to run. I immediately shut it down by use of the power button. The same script came up every time I shut it down about 4 times now.

I double checked the ISO verification on the same tails (2.0) I downloaded it gave this

tails-I386-2.0 ISO untrusted valid signature. 
Valid but untrusted sighed by on 2016-01-26

On tails 1.8.1 it gives

tails -I386-2.0 ISO good signature 
sighed by on 2016-01-26

What should I do. Should I let this script run? Is this normal? Is it a one time thing? Is this  because it is Debian 8 (Jessie)? Does this happen to your download as well?

Comment: Can you post the sha256 hash of your iso image?
(Current sha256 of tails2: `d082ba8bc3dabb9b26795e077dd7733e`)

Comment: 78167d14bc42080a456789a1f1b91554a819050fdf1aae33dc293f284256bba7  tails-i386-2.0.iso.     your shasum is incorrect this is a valid Shasum as appears in the tails web site.

Comment: Verified shasum from both older version of tails and Ubuntu shasum256 matches that of tails website.

Comment: Sorry got them mixed up mine one is a MD5 sum.